# Wordpress PHP Syntax Loop is strange

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having trouble understanding this code. I get the basics of the 'wordpress-loop' but I dont understand what some of this syntax. It almost looks like a ternary operator.

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1>  
            <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; else: ?>

            <p>Sorry, this page does not exist</p>

        <?php endif; ?>
```

Specifically this line..

```
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
```

It is saying OK If there are posts, while we have posts, show the post? But what do the :'s signify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [PHP alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for control structures:

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures;
>   namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic
>   form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon
>   (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;,
>   or endswitch;, respectively.

Example:

```
if (condition) : 

endif;
```

is the same as:

```
if (condition) {

}
```

Specifically, WordPress is saying: if we have posts, loop through each post, and get the post.

Here is an indented version to be clear:

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <?php the_post(); ?>

            <h1><?php the_title() ;?></h1>  
            <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else: ?>

        <p>Sorry, this page does not exist</p>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

> PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch. In each case, the basic form of the alternate syntax is to change the opening brace to a colon (:) and the closing brace to endif;, endwhile;, endfor;, endforeach;, or endswitch;, respectively.